# ConstraintLayout problem: some buttons are invisible

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm still trying to understand `ConstraintLayout`.

Let's say I have this activity:

[image]

Which consists of a `RecyclerView` and 3 `Buttons`. The `RecyclerView` may contains lots of `items`. Those 3 `Buttons` stay on the bottom of the screen.

The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".ScanResultActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_buy_more"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Buy More"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/recycler_view" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_checkout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Checkout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/btn_buy_more" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Logout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/btn_checkout" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the result:

[image]

Why only 1 button is visible there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one button visible because it is over the others as it is set to align **Bottom to Bottom**.

If you want to set one button above the other you should use **Bottom to Top** constraint.

I do not know the exactly order you want to set this up, but it should be something like this:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_buy_more"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Buy More"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/recycler_view" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_checkout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Checkout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_buy_more" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Logout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_checkout" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

First issue, your `RecyclerView`'s height was set to `match_parent`, and it was not constrained to the top of the view.

Second issue, your buttons are constrained on the bottom, when it should be their top that is constrained to the bottom of the element above them.

Here is your layout file reworked :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ScanResultActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_buy_more"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_buy_more"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Buy More"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_checkout" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_checkout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Checkout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_logout" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Logout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result :

[image]

Comment: I used the wrong version of the layout file. Please see updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Set Your `Buttons` in `LinearLayout`

Like the Following Code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler_view">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_buy_more"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Buy More"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/recycler_view"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_checkout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Checkout"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/btn_buy_more"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Logout"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/btn_checkout"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope it's Works....

Comment: Using a nested `LinearLayout` completely defeats the purpose of `ConstraintLayout`, which is to have a flat view hierarchy.